# Applying NSMutableAttributedString to a range of text

Tags: swift, uilabel, nsmutableattributedstring

I have some text:

> New Content - Published Today | 10 min read

I'd like to apply styles to everything after and including the pipe, so `| 10 min read`

I have tried the below but it has only styles the pipe itself.

```swift
  func makeAttributedText(using baseString: String?) -> NSMutableAttributedString? {
    guard let baseString = baseString else { return nil }
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: baseString, attributes: nil)
    let timeToReadRange = (attributedString.string as NSString).range(of: "|")
    attributedString.setAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)], range: timeToReadRange)
    return attributedString
  }
```

Comment: as `timeToReadRange` you only define the range of "|" `(attributedString.string as NSString).range(of: "|")`You should create a range starting from "|" to end index.

Comment: That is what I am unsure how to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than getting the *range* of a single character get the *index* of the character and create a range from that index to the end of the string.

```
func makeAttributedText(using baseString: String?) -> NSMutableAttributedString? {
    guard let baseString = baseString else { return nil }
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: baseString, attributes: nil)
    guard let timeToReadIndex = baseString.firstIndex(of: "|") else { return attributedString }
    let timeToReadRange = NSRange(timeToReadIndex..., in: baseString)
    attributedString.setAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)], range: timeToReadRange)
    return attributedString
}
```

Note:

Swift has dedicated methods to convert `Range<String.Index>` to `NSRange`. There's no reason for the bridge cast to `NSString`